# Insert drop caps text in android

Tags: android

I am learning Android and the following is part of an assignment.

I need to write some text in an Android layout with the first letter in drop caps, like the following text:

[image]

I looked up the web and did not find many answers. Is there a style option or some property that I could use?

At the moment, I am thinking of the following options. Please suggest what is the best way to do such a thing

1. Use an image for the first letter
2. Write the first letter separately in a big font.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: If I were you, I would likly to try your second option. Also I didn't understand why so many downvotes

Comment: better you write the first letter separately in a big font.

Comment: @GhostDerfel : I do not understand the downvotes myself. I think people read 'Assignment' and think 'he wants us to do his homework' and press the downvote. 

Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this.. Cheers !!

Comment: Just added an upvote to try to revert this, also if you find any good solution will be great if you post some code or layout xml in the answer

Comment: I don't see a reason for the down votes, and I would do the second option.

Comment: @GhostDerfel : I would definitely post once I find a good solution.
NenMa,kabuto178 : Thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `RelativeSizeSpan`.

```
    final String someText = "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away";
    final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(someText);
    ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(5f), 0, 1, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, this solution keeps the baseline of the enlarged letter in the same place as the rest of the first line of text. If the text were longer, the second line would have text directly below the enlarged letter. Is there a solution that actually produces a proper drop cap?

Comment: @Karakuri you can use the Library mentioned in the comment by me below. The library ensures that the DropCap is properly aligned with the remaining text.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library written by Novoda in which you can add a `DropCap` https://github.com/novoda/spikes/tree/master/drop-cap
Here's an image from the demo app:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please follow GitHub sample app

https://github.com/datanapps/CapTextView

```
<datanapps.captextview.CapTextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
    
    app:capsDropNumber="2"
    app:capFont="@font/eb_garamond_regular"
    app:capTextColor="@color/purple_700"
    app:capTextSize="@dimen/cap_text_size"

    app:bodyTextColor="@color/purple_700"
    app:bodyTextSize="@dimen/body_text_size"
    app:bodyTextFont="@font/eb_garamond_regular"
    />
```

[image]

Hope it will help

Comment: In your example the drop cap is horribly misaligned. Not sure if this is a good way to promote using this library... ;)