# Android : Different left margins to lines in a single textview to achieve drop cap design

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to assign different margins to lines in a single textview in android? Basically i want to display first three lines from Horizontal middle and rest from Horizontal starting of textview. I am trying to create a drop cap kind of UI.Please help.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085067/insert-drop-caps-text-in-android

Comment: this solution keeps the baseline of the enlarged letter in the same place as the rest of the first line of text. If the text were longer, the second line would have text directly below the enlarged letter. Is there a solution that actually produces a proper drop cap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to my own Question, hope it may help some one. I solved it by following below link.

http://grishma102.blogspot.jp/2013/12/how-to-make-text-flow-around-images-in.html

```
@Override  
 Public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )   
 {  
     super . onCreate ( savedInstanceState ) ;  
     setContentView ( R. layout . main ) ;   
   String text = getString ( R. string . text ) ;   
   // Get the icon and its width  
   Drawable DICON = getResources ( ).getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);   
   int = leftMargin DICON. getIntrinsicWidth ( ) + 10 ;   
   //Set the icon in R.id.icon   
    ImageView icon =(ImageView)findViewById(R.ID.icon ) ;  
    icon.setBackgroundDrawable (DICON) ;  
   SpannableString SS = New SpannableString (text);   
   //Expose the indent for the first three rows  
    SS.setSpan(New MyLeadingMarginSpan2(3,leftMargin),0,SS.length(),0);  
    TextView MessageView = ( TextView ) findViewById ( R. ID . message_view ) ;  
     MessageView. setText ( SS ) ;   
 }  



class MyLeadingMarginSpan2 implements LeadingMarginSpan2 {  
     private int margin;  
     private int lines;  
     MyLeadingMarginSpan2(int lines, int margin) {  
       this.margin = margin;  
       this.lines = lines;  
     }  
    /*Returns the value to which must be added indentation*/  
     @Override  
     public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {  
       if (first) {  
        / *This * indentation is applied to the number of          rows returned * getLeadingMarginLineCount ()*/   
       return margin;  
       }  
      else  
      {  
     //Offset for all other Layout layout ) { }  
     /*Returns * the number of rows which should be applied *     indent returned by getLeadingMargin (true)   
     * Note:* Indent only applies to N lines of the first paragraph.*/   
       return 0;  
       }  
     }  
     @Override  
     public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir,  
         int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text,   
         int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {}  
   @Override  
     public int getLeadingMarginLineCount() {  
       return lines;  
     }  
   };
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OBIX.png)

Comment: Your own question`s answer is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.
For this kind of operations maybe it's better using a webview and writing the text inside using html tags.

Otherwise try to force the rappresentation in the TextView adding spaces to the String you are going to view.

Comment: I have an idea of using Webview but my string will have spannable click listeners where user can click each sentence in a paragraph. So if i use web view to load text it will not detect click events. So i was just curious about how to implement this.